# Object literal notation getter and setter: too much recursion

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am new to scripting with js and following JavaScript guide of MDN. I am not able to understand some js concepts easily.

Tried the following code(from Java background) but it is giving too much recursion error by the browser.

```
//jshint esnext: true
console.clear();

var student = {
    get name() {
        return this.name;
    },

    set name(value) {//Should we not use same name as local variable?
        this.name = value;
    },

    get age() {
        return this.age;
    },

    set age(value) {
        this.age = value;
    }
};

var mike = Object.create(student);
console.log(mike.age);
console.log(mike.name);

mike.age = 29;
console.log(mike.age);

mike.name = "JS";
console.log(mike.name);
```

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should be referencing a private variable in the context of the getter and setter, instead of referencing the same name. A common pattern is to prefix each local variable with an underscore, compared to the public name.

```
var student = {
    get name() {
        return this._name;
    },

    set name(value) {//Should we not use same name as local variable?
        this._name = value;
    },

    get age() {
        return this._age;
    },

    set age(value) {
        this._age = value;
    }
};
```

Comment: Is the function returning itself?

Comment: Yeah like you said in your comment, the getter will call itself recursively resulting in the maximum call stack exceeded error.

Comment: Say I have studentAge and studentName properties with default values. Then I can refer to those properties directly. Then how do they become private? What do you mean by private members in your answer?

Comment: Private was probably not the best term there, as it can still be accessed externally but would typically not be documented.

Comment: Ugh.  So if I want to use a getter and a setter to simply trap accesses to particular properties, without having shadow properties which technically can be accessed and used to bypass my traps, it can't be done?

Comment: Unfortunately that's the nature of javascript, there's no such thing as true private variables. However you can accomplish something very similar with some of the techniques here https://css-tricks.com/implementing-private-variables-in-javascript/